# Create a smooth curve from a series of GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have looked at a lot of Q/A here on SO regarding similar (if not the same) question I have. Yet none had an answer I was able to understand.

I wish to input a series of GPS coordinates, and create a smooth curve that connects them all, and passes through ALL of them. Javascript is my preferred language and I have found this page

http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/curvesbezier.htm

It allows you to plot any number of points and when clicking the 'Draw Curve' button it does exactly what I want (except it is on html5 canvas whereas I want to use lat/lon values)

You can download the jsDraw2D source code here:

http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/download.htm

The function in question is drawCurve() and it appears to calculate the points of the curve, creating a separate 'div' for each point as it goes along, while also appending them to the html page. I am presuming I need to get rid of the code for creating the html divs and instead add each point as it is calculated to an array or string. However, it is simply over my head (perhaps because it seems overwhelming and my understanding is not quite spot on).

I would post the code here, but it is pretty long, plus I am not sure how many other functions it calls/requires from the rest of the script.

The only other thing I can think of that needs to be considered is the +/- values in GPS coordinates. I am hoping that altitude changes would not effect the smooth line created too much, especially since it seems to create the new points so close together.

Any help in modifying that code would be greatly appreciated. If someone has some other approach, I am open to suggestions - however I would prefer a way that passes through ALL the input points (unlike some mathematical curve functions that do not)

Thanks!