# An accurate GPS algorithm - Android

Tags: android, algorithm, gps, tracking

I'm currently trying to build a tracking app. I use the GPS straight from the API, but the accuracy is terrible!
On a good day I get 6 meters for half a minute and then it goes jumpy.
I tried in on few devices and it's the same.

What is the correct and good way to make it more accurate? Does anyone know a good algorithm for fixing it? or at least for filtering? something like in NikeRun.

Comment: See this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data

Comment: You could try filtering with a Kalman filter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Comment: Good info in this answer: [Android GPS Coordinates Scattered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14365700/383414)

Comment: @Gil404 I am also facing similiar issue. I hope you had fixed this issue, kindly share it will be useful.