# How to figure out when a gps coordinate is valid in Android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location

I'm developing an Android app and I need some help to save GPS coordinates for a **route**... coordinates are very important for my app, so: how can I do in order to get very good coordinates (especially at a first try)? How can I understand whether the **position is correct or not**? How can I use ***getAccuracy*** method or similar to figure out whether the position is wrong so that I have to reject it?

For example: I get a 1st *LatLng* coordinate but the 2nd *LatLng* is located 100 meters away from the 1st coordinate, so I guess that **is very unlikely** that a user can move 100 meters away in a few seconds... how can I create such an alghoritm?

Comment: This is a good post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14365700/5053585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Defining a Model for the Best Performance to get location

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply... sometimes I get false coordinate, like I said especially at a first try... for example it use the last WiFi MACID but if I'm in another city my route is wrong bad... do you say with this implementation I won't have this problem again?

Comment: this is special case. i implement this algorithm one of my application (mobile spy) and i got best result. false coordinate may be depends on devices.

Comment: Can you suggest me something to do with devices? I'm thinking to use (if there is) step counter or acceleration sensor to check if there is some suspicious coordinates.
Thanks again

Comment: did you write your logic in onLocationChanged ?

Comment: `@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if ( location.hasAccuracy() && location.getAccuracy() < MINIMUM_ACCURACY ) {
            if (isBetterLocation(location, currentBestLocation)){
                //handle new location
            }
        }
    }`